# Ошибка Cannot Cast

Tags: c#

[image: Сам текст ошибки]

```
internal static T Get < T > (string key) where T: new() {
    if (Configs.ContainsKey(key)) {
        return (T) Config.Configs[key];
    }

    return new T();
}

public static Dictionary < string, object > Configs;

var te = Get < List < string >> ("Шляпа");

public static ConfigFile Default() {
    Configs = new Dictionary < string, object > {
        {
            "Шляпа",
            new List < string > () {
                "Test1",
                "Test2",
                "Test3"
            }
        }
    };
    return this;
}
```

Configs сериализуется в json file.Но Если при считывание получаю ошибку!В чем я ошибся?

Comment: _В чем я ошибся?_ - в типах, очевидно. Раз получаешь ошибку InvalidCast - значит полученный объект ты не можешь скастить в указанный тип. Смотри какой у тебя реальный тип объекта и в какой тип ты его хочешь перевести.

Comment: @Grundy добавляю как List<string> как object - так же и получаю

Comment: У тебя код странный: наличие ключа ты проверяешь в `Configs`, а значение берешь из `Config.Configs`

Comment: @Grundy Config это название класса

Comment: Плюс возврат какого-то `this` из статической функции. То что ты привел - даже не скомпилируется. Поэтому добавь в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: Возможно, при десериализации создаётся объект массив (`Array`), который нельзя привести к `List<string>`. Лучше приводить к `ICollection<string>` или к `IReadOnlyCollction<string>`.

Comment: @Grundy класс не статический - просто забыл удалить this

Comment: @MarkShevchenko JArray возращает

Comment: @Костя, `JArray` очевидно не то же самое что `List<string>`

Answer (score -1):

Решение ошибки!

```
internal static T Get < T > (string key) {
    if (Configs.ContainsKey(key)) {
        if (Configs[key].GetType() == typeof(JArray)) {
            Configs[key] = ((JArray) Configs[key]).ToObject(typeof(T));
        }
        if (Configs[key].GetType() == typeof(JObject)) {
            Configs[key] = ((JObject) Configs[key]).ToObject(typeof(T));
        }
        return (T) Config.Configs[key];
    }

    return default (T);
}
```